# Android studio appengine endpoint doesn't include builder

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

Working in android studio 1.2.2 with two modules: android and the other is the endpoint that was generated from the class and is called 'backend' for the app-engine module. When trying to use the endpoint, the IDE gives an error for SearchObjectEndpoint.Builder

Endpoint class:

```
public class SearchObject {

    private String Location;

    public String getLocation() {
        return Location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        Location = location;
    }
}
```

Generated Endpoint:

```
@Api(
        name = "searchObjectApi",
        version = "v1",
        resource = "searchObject",
        namespace = @ApiNamespace(
                ownerDomain = "SearchPackage.Package.backend.co.za",
                ownerName = "SearchPackage.Package.backend.co.za",
                packagePath = ""
        )
)
public class SearchObjectEndpoint {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SearchObjectEndpoint.class.getName());

    @ApiMethod(name = "getSearchObject")
    public SearchObject getSearchObject(@Named("id") Long id) {
        return null;
    }

    @ApiMethod(name = "insertSearchObject")
    public SearchObject insertSearchObject(SearchObject searchObject) {
        return searchObject;
    }
}
```

In android project when i call SearchObjectEndpoint.Builder it does not find the Builder..

```
import za.co.backend.Package.SearchPackage.SearchObjectEndpoint;
 ...
 SearchObjectEndpoint.Builder builder = new SearchObjectEndpoint.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
```

The app build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
```

backend build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.18'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.18'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.18'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.1.5'
    compile 'com.ganyo:gcm-server:1.0.2'
}

appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
    endpoints {
        getClientLibsOnBuild = true
        getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
    }
```

I read through other similar problems on stackoverflow, but they seem outdated or do not solve the problem. Please Help

Comment: Hi, I'm having this issue as well, could it be the app-engine version?

Comment: That's something I have been thinking might be a issue aswell, not sure though. I have been struggling to install the newest version though, got any good tutorial to follow to do so?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was not using the correct object for the Builder:

I used the autogenerated Endpoints Class, SearchObjectEndpoint, in stead of the endpoint @Api(name = **searchObjectApi**)

I was trying to:

```
SearchObjectEndpoint.Builder builder = new SearchObjectEndpoint.Builder(AndroidHttp...
```

Instead of:

```
SearchObjectApi.Builder builder = new SearchObjectApi.Builder(AndroidHttp...
```

Comment: Awesome! Yes, I had some troubles with GAE version and objectify, cheers!